# Ambiguous use of subscript using [indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, ambiguous

After I updated to Xcode 7.2 an error popped up saying "Ambiguous use of subscript" at the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      /*ERROR - Ambiguous use of subscript*/
      cell.textLabel?.text = self.tvArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? String 

      //..... more code
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong when implementing tvArray?

**The setup:**

```
var tvArray = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)

  //..... more code
  tvArray = [["Airing Today", "On The Air", "Most Popular", "Top Rated"], ["Action & Adventure", "Animation", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama", "Family", "Kids", "Mystery", "News", "Reality", "Sci-Fic & Fantasy", "Soap", "Talk", "War & Politics", "Western"]]
  //..... more code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tvArray = []` without explicit type is inferred to `[AnyObject]`.

Tell the compiler the proper type of the array: An `Array` containing arrays of `String`.
Then it knows that the array can be subscripted by index.

```
var tvArray = Array<[String]>()
```

or

```
var tvArray = [[String]]()
```

Additional benefit: The type casting in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not needed

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.tvArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks I guess I forgot that part. The weird thing is the compiler didn't complain in 7.1 :0